# How can I add emission node to volume scatter to create cloud light using point density texture node?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, shaders

How can I add emission node to volume scatter to create like this 
[image]

using point density texture node? I tried a lot of way but I have not found any solution. I know this node may be looks very complex. But also a way to understand  how to process cycles nodes. If you could help me, I'd very appreciate it.

Comment: Only through blender nodes. This is explained in one blender conference back in 2014 about point clouds. Volumes can be emissive. I'd recommend you to "substract" with a second point cloud to OCCLUDE certain areas.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I find the conference here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pkAfRkT67ao&list=PLa1F2ddGya__tVlgy0KNkF4ns8sNUF-2N&index=25, but I don't know which one that you mention. Do you remember the conference?

Answer (score 0):

Have 2 different set of volumes (one very short of emission particles) and the other one to occlude it with a much denser but scattered point cloud. Might work after some texture maths (substract, divide)

Answer (score 0):

If the smoke is made with a simulation, the density is an attribute that can be referenced in the shader tree.

[image]